# Поиск двойного вхождения строки

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения

Задание такое:

> В файл  data  напишите выражение  abbaxabaxabbax  и напишите регулярное выражение для нахождения слова abbax таким образом, чтобы оно дважды совпадало в строке.

`grep 'abbax{2}' data.txt` не работает.

Comment: Каков ожидаемый результат? 2? Или просто вывести на экран 2 строки `abbax`? `grep -o abbax data.txt`?

Comment: Как я понял задание, в строке должна дважды упоминаться подстрока "abbax", причем в любой части (не обязательно подряд). Вывод - строка, где выполнилось данное условие (либо несколько строк).

Comment: `grep 'abbax.*abbax' data.txt`? См. https://ideone.com/ayHGQF

Comment: Вроде работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```bsh
grep 'abbax.*abbax' data.txt
```

Шаблон `abbax.*abbax` найдёт совпадение в строчке, в которой есть минимум два совпадения `abbax`.

См. [пример работы скрипта](https://ideone.com/ayHGQF):

```bsh
s='abbaxabaxabbax
abbax
abaxabbax
abbax ab a x abbax xxxxx'
grep 'abbax.*abbax' <<< "$s"
# => abbaxabaxabbax
#    abbax ab a x abbax xxxxx
```

Если в сточке должно быть только два совпадения и не более, использйте

```bsh
grep 'abbax.*abbax' data.txt | grep -v 'abbax.*abbax.*abbax'
```

Ещё один вариант с использованием регулярного выражения PCRE (для GNU grep):

```bsh
grep -P '^(?!(.*abbax){3})(?:.*?abbax){2}'
```

См. [пример работы кода онлайн](https://ideone.com/gt02qw).

Comment: если исходить из примера, написанного автором вопроса, то `grep '\(abbax.*\)\{2\}'`